# Purpose of checking session.use_only_cookies when creating a session?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, ini

I am currently creating a session where I check the ini file to see if `use_only_cookies` is set. Is this really necessary? I mean, is there a way for the client to mess with the `ini` file? The reason why I am asking is because if the user is redirected to the same domain, this check would just loop over and over again.

How can I prevent this when the session is global? or is this even necessary to add when creating a session?

```
$session_life   = 3600;
$session_name   = 'SecUser';
$http_only      = true;
if(ini_set('session.use_only_cookies',1) === false){
   header('500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
   exit();
}
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params($session_life, $cookieParams['path'], $cookieParams['domain'], $secure, $http_only);
session_name($session_name);
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(false);
```

Comment: It is not “necessary”, it just depends on what level of security you want. (In case it is news to you, that transporting the session id by other means than cookie is considered less safe and why, then please go read up on it.)

Comment: @CBroe No, no, of course not, but how could the client change the ini file so that this wouldn't be true anymore? Server side I have already defined ALL sessions to use cookies. This just checks if it is written there... why check?

Comment: _“This just checks if it is written there... why check?”_ – because one day the script might get used on a different server with a different configuration …

Comment: @CBroe Okai, thanks. Then I'll keep that in mind when working with the sessions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it's not necessary.

And no, the client can't mess with the `ini` file. That's for sure.

If you just want a standard session with a session id, you can do it the quick and easy way: Just use `session_start()` - and that's it! No `ini_set()`, no `session_get_cookie_params()`, no `session_set_cookie_params()`, no `session_name()`, no `session_regenerate_id()`. All those functions are only required for special cases.

In some environments (e.g. shared hosting) you don't have access to `php.ini`. That's why PHP lets you get and/or set some of those settings from whithin the app. Besides, there might be some (very exotic) use cases where somebody would want to change this `ini` setting dynamically...

See here: http://php.net/manual/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-only-cookies
They clearly recommend to have this set to `true`. The purpose of this very setting is: Before cookies where (a) invented and/or (b) popular, PHP had a fallback mechanism for users who couldn't (or refused to) accept cookies. In this case the session id was somehow appended to every (!) URL. Very few use this today, since today almost everybody accepts cookies (at least session cookies), since every website uses them ;-)

Now for your question: No, this wouldn't crash anything. Actually, for 99.99% of all users it wouldn't make a difference! The setting just deactivates the **fallback** from cookie to URL.
The absolute worst case is that a non-cookie enabled user is not going to get the session.

Somewhat offtopic: Checking for failures this way doesn't make sense to me anyway: If you try to catch a problem you should either inform the user about what they could do now or (even better) try to process it in another way. Just throwing a 500 error and exiting doesn't make much of a difference since this is what PHP does anyway when it crashes...

Comment: What is the special case to require to check if ini_set if I know this by looking at the ini file? :) The others I understand, just not the reason to check ini_set...

Comment: Okai, great! :) Thanks for the enlightment. What would happen if a user accessed the page when ini file is set to false, and redirected to another page which also starts the session? would this loop and "crash" the request?